# Aligning object and button

Tags: html, css

The following is the code

```
<object id="conv1" type="image/svg+xml" data="conv1.svg"></object>
<p align="center">
<button><span>Play/Replay</span></button>
</p>
```

I want to align the button center with respect to object. How could that be achieved?
If I try to align the button center, it gets aligned with respect to page.
Here is the website link.
http://mathsbeauty.esy.es/temp2.html

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.  for starters, please add a [mcve] to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a width on a parent element then it will align correctly.

```
<div style="width: 504px;">
  <object id="conv1" type="image/svg+xml" data="conv1.svg"></object>
  <p style="text-align: center;">
    <button><span>Play/Replay</span></button>
  </p>
</div>
```

If you are not able to specify a width then you could use the @Lahiru Ashan's solution. If you still require the contents to be left aligned then you could add the following:

```
<div style="text-align:center; float: left;">
  <object id="conv1" type="image/svg+xml" data="conv1.svg"></object>
  <p><button><span>Play/Replay</span></button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like I was slow typing.@Ingvi's solution would be my favoured solution if flexbox is an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

give **width** to **p** tag as your **object** width

i have created demo:

```html
<div style="width:504px;height:458px;background-color:red;">
</div>
<p align="center" style="width:504px;">
  <button><span>Play/Replay</span>
  </button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <object id="conv1" type="image/svg+xml" data="conv1.svg"></object>
   <p align="center">
   <button><span>Play/Replay</span></button>
   </p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to achive this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <object></object>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find width of `<object>` tag and apply width in style of `<p>` tag as below code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  

   var width = document.getElementById('conv1').offsetWidth
   var p=document.getElementsByTagName('p');

   //use index as per `p` tag position in your html.
   p[0].style.width = width+"px";

})
```

hope that help!

Comment: Thanks PaulBGD for pointing this, You are right, but it depends on situation and it is one of the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both of them with a div and set the div's width to the SVG's width to center the button.

```
.container {
  width: 500px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tug1hudo/